# Surface : Multi focus, multi touch, multi applications

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I'm currently developping an application with Surface SDK running two windows (not hard to reproduce at all).

Problem is : when 1st window is clicked, she has the focus. But when I want to click the 2nd window while first is still clicked, I can't get the focus and interact with this 2nd window.

I think problem is that Windows only gives the focus to one application at a time, so you can't interact with a second window until first click is released.

Do someone know if there is a solution to force windows to interact with 2 applications at the same time ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct but unfortunately there is no solution.  Much of Windows is based on an assumption that only one window has focus.  (Source: I lead the team that created the Surface SDK)

Comment: I wanted a reliable confirmation of what I thought, and according to what you did, your answer is one.

Thanks for you answer sir !

Answer (score 0):

A tool such as PluralInput may work for you:

https://pluralinput.com/